# Logic in PySpark Dataframe to allocate a value over N rows given intervals

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my first post here and I would need your support to achieve this result.
I have a dataframe which contains values like :

[original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWr1M.png)

What i want to achieve is something like this:
[final df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU4u4.png)

Do you have any idea of how I can achieve this?

I tried several window function but im not able to get the o/p I want

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)